# How to create a split background color layout in pure CSS

Tags: html, css, styles, background-image, background-color

I'm trying to create a footer for a site that has this split color design, where's there's two triangles almost overlapping one another. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

[image]

I attempted something like this:

```
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #ba5459 48%, #97444c 48%);
```

Comment: **2** linear-gradient and a padding  will easily do this visual , you almost have it.

Comment: Yup, that's the route to go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not overlapping triangles its a special CSS property called clip-path which is used to clip the rectangular div into various shapes.
Create a div first and then in CSS paste the following property. Play with the values to understand its behavior.

```
clip-path: polygon(0 24%, 100% 0%, 100% 99%, 0% 100%);
```

You can learn more about clip path over [there.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Comment: This seems to be almost working... I've got a parent div with the darker red as a background-color. Then a div inside of that with the alternate red as a background-color and the clip-path styling above.

Comment: Here's a fiddle to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/abed8grs/6/#&togetherjs=lbcn2V28N9

Comment: Final, working css code:
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%, #ba5459 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 49.5%,#97444c 50%);